# Get userid in facebook from its e-mail using c#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using Facebook API how i can get userid in facebook from its mail ?

I am using Facebook.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Search API, you can query all publicly available information. That means, you can get user ID if the user allowed his e-mail address to be public.
You would issue a query something like:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=user@example.com&type=user&access_token=...
```

The JSON response would be:

```
{
      "data": [
        {
         "name": "Firstname Lastname"
         "id": "123456799"
        }
   ]
}
```

If the user's address is not public, you will get an empty data.

I'm not aware if there is an implementation for this in C#, but you can easily make one.

Comment: I am using desktop application how can I do this on it ?

Comment: and where I can found search api can you please put a post url to it and how to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
dynamic result = fb.Get("/search", parameters);
```

should be changed into something like:

```
dynamic result = fb.Get("/me", parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do it using Facebook C# SDK.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.q = "user@example.com";
parameters.type = "user";
dynamic result = fb.Get("/search", parameters);
```

If user is found you will get exactly one result.

```
if(result.data.Count == 1){
    var uid = result.data[0].id;
}
```